# How does free() deallocate a block of Memory when only given the Start Address?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm currently working on my own Implementation of an Array-like Datatype for learning purposes.
My Problem is understanding how the `free()` functions knows how much to deallocate since I only pass in the Pointer to the start address of the allocated Memory.

The Parameter for the `free()` function is called block but I only pass in the "start" of the Block. Or do I have a fundamental misconception about heap allocation?

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: The heap block has an information header so that the manager can tell what size it has.

Comment: It is _very_ unlikely that using `free` in your C++ code is correct. It should almost surely be `new[]`/`delete[]` instead of `malloc`/`free` and `new[]`/`delete[]` _do_ sometimes store extra information about the array size.

Comment: In a typical implementation, there's an information block in front of the memory that the pointer points to; in other words, at negative offset. `malloc` allocates more memory than the application asks for, writes its bookkeeping information at the beginning of the block, then returns the pointer pointing to the byte right after that bookkeeping information. `free` does the reverse.

Comment: Here is a good write-up on the glibc implementation if you are interested in finer details of a modern implementation: https://azeria-labs.com/heap-exploitation-part-1-understanding-the-glibc-heap-implementation/

Comment: @Homer512 Thanks! The Article seems to have all the information I need

Comment: @user17732522 I didn't think about just using new/new[] tbh but this seems to be way better especially because I had some issues with forgetting to cast to the correct Type when using calloc and wondering why I get strange errors.

Comment: @user17732522 It's not "very unlikely" for malloc/free to be incorrect - they are just different, and don't fully fit into the C++ system so they are sometimes incorrect.

Comment: @LeonSchultz Just using `malloc`/`calloc`/`free` without any `new` has undefined behavior in C++ for most types. It is only very specific, so-called _implicit-lifetime types_ that can be used directly without `new`. It is unlikely that you are consciously considering that, so simply don't use `malloc` etc. in your C++ code.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, and I highly doubt that OP is aware of the conditions under which `malloc` etc. are vaild, while `new`/`delete` is always valid.